# Netty 4, use the current thread for an HTTP client

Tags: netty

I would like to write an HTTP client, using Netty 4, that does not requires the creation of any additional thread.

I started working from the HttpSnoopClient and tried replacing:

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
```

with:

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup(1, new Executor() {
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        command.run();
    }
});
```

But the program hangs on:

```
ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect(host, port);
```

The *Netty in Action* book does not mention such a possibility but I had some hope (setting the appropriate callbacks or listeners here and there...). Right now I am wondering if it is even possible.

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible as the Thread will be used to block on the Selector, so you will need at least one extra Thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and for writing the book: very instructive, very helpful)!